# Specifying units for shapefile using QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I'm trying to create a shapefile of fields, drawing polygons around each field, and having the acreage calculated in the attribute table. I believe I have the projections correct. It's not coming up with accurate figures.

How do I correct this?

Answer (score 3):

The units are based on your projection, either meters, feet, or degrees.  If you're calculating area with a projected dataset you're either getting square meters or square feet, you'll need to apply the appropriate conversion factor to get acres.

Answer (score 3):

The units are associated to the project you create the shapefile as.  If you set it as a UTM projection, you will be working in meters.  If you use a Lat/Long projection, you will be working in degrees.  If you are using a State Plane projection, you will be working in feet.  Within the attribute table when you are calculating you can always perform a conversion on the calculated area.